# 'struct x' declared inside parameter list

Tags: c, function, struct

can someone pls help me.

language: C

```
int func(struct Dog A, struct Dog B); //func.h header

test=func(A,B); //main.c main

int test(struct Dog *A,struct Dog *B){

    int test=0;



    return test;
}//func.c functions

//Structs:

struct date {
int day;
int month;
int year;
};

struct Dog {
char name[50];
struct date birthdate;
int age;
}A,B;
```

warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want

warning: 'struct Dog' declared inside parameter list

we haven't learned anything about pointers so please remind that but i think for that you will need thos.

Comment: Why don't you have structure definitions in the header?

Comment: Atleast, put the structure definitions before using them.

Comment: I did. here: int func(struct Dog A, struct Dog B);

Comment: Provide a [mcve]! If that is exactly the code you compile: This is not valid C for various reasons and you should consult a C book for the basics.

Comment: Make sure you have the definition for `struct Dog` *before* the function prototypes that refer to it in their parameters.

Comment: ...and fix the prototype to read ...`*A` and `*B`,

Comment: you don'tneed the whole code. It's very long. Please just tell me what's wrong :c.

Comment: Two people already told you how to fix the error you mentioned... but the seemingly random bits of code you pasted don't make much sense as shown (out of order and out of context).  Also, it looks like you have both functions and variables named `test`... which is probably not a great idea.

Comment: i added * in front of every A.Now the warnings are gone but i go a new error at: test=func(*A,*B);:                                                                            incompatible type for argument 1 of 'test'
..\/func.h:28:5: note: expected 'struct Dog *' but argument is of type 'struct Dog'

Comment: @Dmitri no i have a prototype in func.h, a functioncall in the main and the function itself in the func.c

Comment: everyone says: fix the prototype. but how, whats wrong?

Comment: Your function takes parameters of type `struct Dog` and your error indicates that the compiler hasn't been told what `struct Dog` *is* yet at that point.  You need the definition of `struct Dog` (shown at the bottom of your pasted code) to come *before* your function prototype (either directly or via an include), so that it's already defined when the compiler gets there.

Comment: @Dmitri thank you. So i have to write the drfinition above the #include <stdio.h>?

Comment: No, it just needs to be before `int func(struct Dog A, struct Dog B);`.  Also, the name and parameter types of the function in the prototype need to match the name and parameters of the function definition.

Comment: it is before. wher should i write int func(struct Dog A, struct Dog B);? it is before

Comment: What @Olaf said.. this is guessing game so far.

Comment: my code has 320 words, 2040 characters.Maybe you think thats not much but thats to much for this little problem. also everything is written in german and I'd have to translate all of it. The only thing thats wrong is that litte line of code the rest of it is correct so you don't need id to help me.:c I will ask my teacher tomorrow.Thank you for your help especially Dmitri, thank you very much! Bye

Answer (score -1):

I would not normally answer this question, because it is trivial (and a duplicate), but it seems that the questioner and/or the commenters on the question are having trouble with English, and I think a very explicit statement with sample code will help.

You need to move the complete declaration of `struct Dog`,

```
struct Dog {
    char name[50];
    struct date birthdate;
    int age;
};
```

to the file you called `func.h header`, and you need to put it *before* the line in that file reading

```
int func(struct Dog A, struct Dog B);
```

That will correct the error you are asking about.  It appears to me that there are several other errors in your code, but without seeing your *actual*, *complete* program, rather than a bunch of fragments, I can't help you with them.

We make a fuss about seeing the actual, complete program, because far too often, when someone posts a bunch of fragments, the problem is in the code they *didn't* post, or it depends on what order the fragments appear in the actual program.  But your intuition that you already posted too much code is good!  We do want you to cut down what you post from the full-size program -- but we want you to keep it a *complete program*, one we can compile and experiment with ourselves.  What we want, ideally, is the *shortest possible complete program* that exhibits the problem you need help with.